# Does DPDK support to launch a new thread by slave?

Tags: dpdk

Documentation of DPDK shows that `rte_eal_remote_launch` can only be called by master lcore. Does it mean I can only launch extra threads in runtime with master thread? Can I assign it to slave threads?

ps: There is another question. The documentation also said things like:

> Note: This function is not designed to offer optimum performance. It
> is just a practical way to launch a function on another lcore at
> initialization time.

What does it mean? Is there another more effiective way to launch a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `logical cores specified as part of EAL Arguments`, one can choose either a single or multiple cores for DPDK LCORE. The DPDK API [rte_eal_remote_launch](http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__launch_8h.html#a2bf98eda211728b3dc69aa7694758c6d) helps to start a specific function with arguments under DPDK context on specific LCORE. If not invoked with the API, the thread will be in wait state (created and waiting to run user application). One should use the API in the `context of the master core for launching new functions` to be running under DPDK EAL context.

> > Can I assign it to slave threads?

[Answer] One run alternative threads or worker threads `other than DPDK lcore threads` also by using

1. Service cores using [rte_service](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/service_cores.html?highlight=lcore) API
2. non-dpdk or non-eal threads using [rte_thread_register](http://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__lcore_8h.html#aa940f21386771ce352e052d5367e5a17)

Please refer the DPDK documentation for sample with explanation for [use of rte_remote_launch](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/hello_world.html?highlight=lcore)